# Free Kontakt Wings Instrument

Tags: kontakt, insects

Who wants a free Kontakt instrument?

This one is a "Wing Machine" I built and decided to share.  It's useful for designing the sound of small winged creatures - dragonflies, beetles, fairies, etc.

With apologies if this sounds like self-promotion or spam - I am giving this away for free, and would love to hear feedback on how this instrument could be improved.  I have heard the question come up on several occasions - how to design winged insects and fairies, so this is more of a solution than a question, but I hope some of you will find it helpful.

[Edit]
I have taken several of Brad Dale's suggestions in the hopes of improving the Wing Machine and have uploaded the new and improved version.
Updates include: Presets Menu, Sample Menu and keyswitches (choose different samples without needing multiple .nki files), adjusted HPF range, LFO menu for multiple flutter types, and surround panner functionality on the GUI.

If there are any Kontakt guru's here that can help me with a few of the instrument's issues, that would be great.

1. When you load the instrument, you won't get any sound out of it until you choose a preset or a sample.  I can't seem to figure out a fix for that issue.
2. The HPF knob, or "Size" knob is somewhat counter-intuitive, with "Large" on the left and "Small" on the right.  If anyone has an easy solution to that problem, I'd be much obliged.
3. Any other suggestions or feedback?

[Download here](http://brycerafflesound.com/WingMachine.zip)

Comment: Some users would consider this spam. SSD is a forum for asking questions, not self-promotion of products. Read: http://socialsounddesign.com/info
Then again, it sounds like a useful library.

Comment: Wrong link sorry: http://socialsounddesign.com/faq

Comment: Fair enough. But I am giving it away for free, not asking for anything in return.  And I have seen this come up on numerous questions across the forum.  It is more of an answer than a question, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, it's free and that's why my response was not a downvote :) And yes other people have done this before you. That however doesn't make it less easy to be mistaken for spam. This is a democratic forum and looking at the current 3 upvotes, tells me not everyone thinks about it in the same way I do. I'm probably a bit too critical on these topics, I guess.

Comment: Honestly, I very much appreciate your comment, and I edited my original question to reflect that concern.  If this is considered spam, I do apologize, and I do appreciate that you did not downvote my post. I do hope that its usefulness and the fact that it's free somewhat trumps the spamminess.  Cheers, and thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Sounds neat. Why is it showing up as Demo though?


Comment: While the instrument itself is free, Kontakt is not.  If you have a copy of Kontakt Player but not the full licensed version of Kontakt, it will show up as a demo and I believe you will be limited to half an hour.  If you have the licensed Kontakt and it is still showing up as a demo, there must be some kind of error going on.

Comment: I have licensed 4 but only player 5. Whatevs.Probably upgrading soon anyway and I couldn't imagine needing it for more than a half hour now, and if i did, i would just restart. Again,good work,pretty usable.

Answer (score 2):

I could see how it would be considered spam, however, I just downloaded. Can't wait to play with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hey Bryce, very cool. thanks for sharing.

I've only had a few minutes to play with it and it's great.

Some feedback on how it could be improved:

1) more source sample material for more varied textures of wings. multiple .nki files

I enjoyed listening to the raw source sample - nature recording.  I threw in a couple of my own samples real quick, set a loop and was easily able to use the instrument on different samples and get slightly different feels or "wing sounds." Adjusting the SV HP filter on the group fx insert allowed more bass and a "bigger wing sound" as well. That could be coded up to the UI as a "wing size" function.

2)  The Panning on the UI.

The surround pan really helps build a "flying around" effect even when in stereo. Putting this up in your custom UI could be killer.

3) Switching the LFO Type.

The rectangle LFO modulation on volume seems to be doing the bulk of the work in terms of the flutter wing sound and obviously rate.  Putting a function on the UI to switch from Rect, to square, sine, etc could provide a "flutter type" functionality for the user.

Over all great little nki. My suggestions are merely ideas/feedback on possible improvement since you asked. :)

Comment: Thanks Brad.  Very good suggestions.  I will definitely look into these ideas.  Really appreciate it.